# Quaternion Electric/Magnetic field reception

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, complex-numbers

I always wondered: why people think of EM field in terms of real numbers, since it exists in 3D space and is described by both direction and strength at some point? Is not it more natural to threat it as quaternions?..

And my question is about possibility of antenna construction. As for electric field sensor - we know electric dipole vibrators: two "sticks" in opposing directions, 1/4 wavelength each. What if i put 4 sticks, so that they would end up in tetrahedron vertices, going towards its middle (but not shorted in the middle) - wouldn't i measure it in 3D? (Blue segments on the drawing)
[image]

Same for magnetic circular loop antennas - may i place four circles, parallel to tethraedron faces? I've failed to find any info on the web, about such antennas construction and methods of sensing EM fields in quaternionic representation. While being bulky in its shape and volume, this could be useful in direction location applications, and for some more advanced and efficient modulation schemes.

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking.  About the construction and viability of such antenna? About its working process? Why is related to quaternions?

Comment: @AlejandroMenaya About the construction and viability of such antenna. Would it work? Can it measure wave polarization in 3D?

Comment: Unfortunately, my knowledge about antennas is not sufficient to provide a satisfiable answer.  I would risk it and say that looks like a reasonable claim.

Comment: You should clarify whether you're asking about using quaternions to represent the EM field, or whether you're asking about your aerial design. We prefer one question per post.

Comment: @JohnRennie I did it: "And my question is about possibility of antenna construction". Isn't is an strict question qualification? Also answered same way in comment above.